# Bootstrap Backbone Marionette Modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js, marionette

I'm trying to create a dialog in backbone and Marionette based on this article:

http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/04/17/managing-a-modal-dialog-with-backbone-and-marionette/

I have a fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/netroworx/ywKSG/

HTML:

```
<script type="text/template" id="edit-dialog">
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
    <h3 id="actionTitle">Create a New Action</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <input type="hidden" id="actionId" name="actionId" />
    <table>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Goal: </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="goal" name="goal" >   <input type="hidden" id="goalid" name="goalid" >
                <a tabindex="-1" title="Show All Items" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-icon-only ui-corner-right ui-combobox-toggle ui-state-hover"
                role="button" aria-disabled="false" >
                    <span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span><span class="ui-button-text"></span>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Action name: </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="actionName" name="actionName">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Target date:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="actionTargetDate" name="actionTargetDate"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="actionActualDateRow">
            <td>Actual date:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="actionActualDate" name="actionActualDate"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
    <a href='#' class="btn btn-primary" id="actionActionLabel">Create Action</a>
</div>

</script>            

<div id="modal"></div>

<a href="#" id="showModal">Show Modal</a>
```

Javascript:

```
var ActionEditView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: "#edit-dialog"
});

function showModal() {
        var view = new ActionEditView();
        view.render();

        var $modalEl = $("#modal");
        $modalEl.html(view.el);
        $modalEl.modal();
}

$('#showModal').click(showModal);
```

When I click on the show modal link the html pane goes dark as expected and the dialog content is displayed but on the background layer.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are missing css classes for div, which should act as modal dialog:

```
<div id="modal" class="modal hide fade"></div>
```